# from twisted.words.protocols import irc no module named words.protocols

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.words

I am trying to create a simple irc client with twisted library and start by importing related module:

```
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
```

This error is displayed:

```
no module named words.protocols
```

I don't quite understand this error as I can import tiwsted directly (it is in my PATH then) and the filesystem is like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py
```

The words and protocols folders both contain a `__init__.py` file, so they should be interpreted as modules.

If I change directory for /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/words/ and start a python interpreter, this command runs without error:

```
from protocols import irc
```

But my final script would have nothing to do in this directory :/

I don't quite understand why I'm having this error and how to solve it.

Many thanks for helping

EDIT

I have all the words folders into `/usr/local/lib` and not in classic `/usr/lib`, maybe python is to look into the second folder and not the first one.

I don't know yet how to overload this behavior, and hope it does not boils down to overriding `os.environ['PATH']` which looks really dirty.

EDIT2: /usr/local/lib folders belong to the PATH as shown by this command:

```
python -c "import sys; print [ i for i in sys.path if 'local' in i ]"
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

So I still don't understand why this shit is not going to be imported

EDIT3

This is not script name related I guess; from a terminal in my debian :

```
python -c "from twisted.words.protocols import irc"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named words.protocols
```

Comment: Is your file, by chance, named `twisted.py`?

Comment: it is not (client.py instead)

Comment: No other `twisted.py` or directory `twisted` in your path? Try running `python2 -v client.py`, to see what it matched your import with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! please have a look at my edited question

Comment: `python2 -v` should be able to tell you what is the **exact** problem.

Comment: Indeed, ``python2 -v`` shows a lot about importing from ``/usr/lib/python2.7/...`` and nothing about ``/usr/local/lib/python2.7`` where ``twisted/words/protocols/irc.py`` lives

Comment: But it finds some kind of `twisted`, as you wouldn't get `no module named words.protocols` but `no module named twisted.words.protocols` instead. Please verify.